# Consulta PostgreSQL - Como fazer essa?

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

Como faço uma consulta SQL nesta tabela:

```
ID Col2 Col1  
-- ---- ----
11   1    A
12   2    D
13   3    G
14   1    B
15   2    E
16   3    H
17   1    C
18   2    F
19   3    I
```

Para retornar este resultado:

```
1   A   B   C
2   D   E   F
3   G   H   I
```

Será que isso é possível?

Answer (score 1):

```
with t (id, c2, c1) as (
    values
        (11, 1, 'A'),
        (12, 2, 'D'),
        (13, 3, 'G'),
        (14, 1, 'B'),
        (15, 2, 'E'),
        (16, 3, 'H'),
        (17, 1, 'C'),
        (18, 2, 'F'),
        (19, 3, 'I')
)
select i, c1[1] as c1, c1[2] as c2, c1[3] as c3
from (
    select c2 as i, array_agg(c1) as c1
    from t
    group by c2
) s
order by 1
;
 i | c1 | c2 | c3 
---+----+----+----
 1 | A  | B  | C
 2 | D  | E  | F
 3 | G  | H  | I
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, sua ideia de ID está errada, cuidado com isso, o ID deve ser único... Você não vai conseguir fazer isso só com Query no SQL, vai ter que fazer isso com a sua linguagem principal...

Em PHP eu faria assim:

```
$resultado = (sua query com a consulta);

foreach($resultado as $key => $value){
    $array[$value->id][] = $value->Col1;
}
```

Com isso você cria um array ($array) com a chave ID e com o resultado da Col1.

Talvez você consiga fazer isso com SQL Server / Oracle com alguma query mais bem elaborada...

Precisa ser query?

Comment: Você está certo... corrigi a tabela. Obrigado.

Comment: STRING_AGG  http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/191-String-Aggregation-in-PostgreSQL,-SQL-Server,-and-MySQL.html

Answer (score 0):

Se `Col1` estiver ordenado, como no exemplo, fica assim para SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp 
( 
    ID INT, 
    Col2 INT,
    Col1 Varchar(1)
)

insert into #tmp (ID, Col2, Col1)
Values
    (11,   1,    'A'),
    (12,   2,    'D'),
    (13,   3,    'G'),
    (14,   1,    'B'),
    (15,   2,    'E'),
    (16,   3,    'H'),
    (17,   1,    'C'),
    (18,   2,    'F'),
    (19,   3,    'I')


select distinct tmp1.Col2, 
                tmp1.Col1, 
                tmp2.Col1,
                tmp3.Col1 
    from #tmp tmp1
        inner join #tmp tmp2
            on  tmp1.Col2 = tmp2.Col2 
            and tmp1.Col1 < tmp2.Col1
        inner join #tmp tmp3
            on  tmp1.Col2 = tmp3.Col2 
            and tmp1.Col1 < tmp3.Col1 
            and tmp2.Col1 < tmp3.Col1
   order by tmp1.Col2
```

Comment: Na verdade a não vai estar ordenado, desta forma o exemplo que você me passou não funcionaria? Obrigado

Comment: Alterei mais uma vez a tabela. A `col1` não está mais ordenada... Obrigado

Comment: Nesse caso, basta adicionar um `order by` ao final. Adicionei uma ordenação ao final. Da mesma forma, conforme você for adicionando mais dados você vai ajustando o Select.